# How can I check an asp checkbox from client side?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a checkbox in the header of the grid and another checkbox on each row of the grid.

```
<tel:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="15px" UniqueName="gridTemplateColumnCheckbox">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkItem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="checkbox-item" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="checkbox-select-all" onclick="toggleSelectAll();" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
</tel:GridTemplateColumn>
```

The thing is that I want to write a function on the client side that will check all the checkbox-item checkboxes when the one in header is checked. I tried to get the checkboxes by class ($('.checkbox-item');) and make the 'checked' property true, but it does not work. Do you have any other ideas? From what I've read when ASP.NET controls render to html they are given another id, so I do not think that I can get the element from id.

Tried to get the checkboxes by class and change the 'checked' property.

Rendered checkboxes look like this:

```
<th scope="col" class="rgHeader">
    <span class="checkbox-item-header"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_chkSelectAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$chkSelectAll"></span>
</th>

<td>
    <span class="checkbox-item"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_chkItem" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl04$chkItem"></span>
</td>

<td>
    <span class="checkbox-item"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl06_chkItem" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl06$chkItem"></span>
</td>

<td>
    <span class="checkbox-item"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl08_chkItem" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl08$chkItem"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: So perhaps post the HTML too? And you are not accessing the checkbox-item by ID but by class

Comment: Can you try $('.checkbox-item input[type="checkbox"]')? Because as i remember, ASP renders checkbox inside a span element at the client side.

Comment: @MetehanTeber somehow the checkboxes are checked/unchecked when I try your solution, but if I log $('.checkbox-item input[type="checkbox"]') is undefined.

Comment: @mplungjan Added the entire html for the grid.

Comment: No you did not. You added the ASP SERVER code. Please load the page into a browser, right-click and choose inspect. Find your checkboxes. Post JUST the RENDERED HTML for the checkboxes including whatever ASP wrapped them in

Comment: @mplungjan sorry, added now

Comment: It works doing something like this $(".checkbox-item input");

Answer (score 0):

This will work on your generated HTML

Alternative selector: `$("[name$=chkItem]").prop("checked",this.checked)`

```js
$(".checkbox-item-header input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
  $(".checkbox-item input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", this.checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th scope="col" class="rgHeader">
      <span class="checkbox-item-header"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_chkSelectAll" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$chkSelectAll"></span>
    </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="checkbox-item"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl04_chkItem" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl04$chkItem"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="checkbox-item"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl06_chkItem" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl06$chkItem"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="checkbox-item"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_contentBody_cphMain_JournalItems1_recItemsGrid_ctl00_ctl08_chkItem" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$contentBody$cphMain$JournalItems1$recItemsGrid$ctl00$ctl08$chkItem"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```